# Android Studio turning black colors to white when switched to dark mode

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

I am new to android studio and I am designing an app which must open a pdf file from the android storage device. I set the background color to black in the activity view and it works fine as long as I am not using my android in Dark mode. Once I turn on dark mode, the background color switches from black to white.

The activity view code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ViewPdfActivity"
android:background="@color/black"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/pdfView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: how it looks when my android is not in dark mode and how i basically want it to look like]

[image: how it looks like when my android is in dark mode and I don't want it look like that]

Themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.PDFwordmeaning" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

night\themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.PDFwordmeaning" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar problem.

https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151800?hl=en

As stated above, Try using dark theme on your phone and Turn on color inversion on your phone, if it fixes the issue. Then your app doesn't support dark theme. So some devices force it which leads to this behavior.

You can fix this by simply adding the following to your style in themes.xml

```
 <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the `theme/night` as that will show the colours that will be used in dark mode. The `theme` will only show colours used during normal usage.

Comment: I've set the color Primary and colorPrimaryDark to black in the night\themes.xml and still I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: can u share the code ? colors.xml, themes.xml and night/themes.xml ?

Comment: i edited the question and now you can see the code of the files you asked for.

Comment: i installed the app on my friend's phone[One Plus] and its running fine in dark mode and apparently i get the white background only on my phone[redmi note 7 pro]. Other pdf viewing apps like Google drive work fine on my device and i wonder what's going wrong in my app

Comment: ok even i havent heard of such a problem yet xD, maybe someone else might be able to help you with it...

Comment: can you check out this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66835042/9350154  Thank yiou