# How to store some text of a pdf file after double tapping it on android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, androidpdfviewer

I am creating a pdf reading app? When a user double taps a text in a pdf file, I want to store that text and perform some operations. I spent a whole day googling things, etc but I don't seem to find any relevant source to do this. I am currently using [this](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) GitHub library to display a pdf from the storage of the android device. which library would you suggest to perform this task? Thank you

Comment: It would appear that the library that you chose is no longer being maintained.

Comment: can you please suggest me some other library or any tutorial really to display a pdf file in my app? because a lot of people on the internet suggested this library.

Comment: I do not know of any currently-maintained open source PDF viewer libraries for Android.

Comment: do you know how i can make my text selectable by one click in the pdf? i have searched so many websites and i didnt find anything at all and it's very demotivating

Comment: Why not use `ACTION_VIEW` and let the user view the PDF in their preferred PDF viewer?

Comment: i wanted to build an app where if you click on a word from a pdf file then the app goes to another activity where the definition of that word from google is displayed and then you could go back to reading the pdf again

Comment: If your company is asking you to do this, perhaps they should look into licensing a commercial PDF rendering library. If this is for yourself, perhaps switch from PDF to HTML and consider a `WebView` and some JavaScript.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you please share me some articles about that? and I'm doing this application for myself. Searched everything on the internet related to the app but i don't seem to find anything at all.

Comment: "Can you please share me some articles about that?" -- some articles about what?

Comment: Any article that might help me develop that feature in the app?